# JSLint syntax comma or semicolon

Tags: javascript, jslint

Hi i am getting compilation error in second line, i am using JSLint.

```
t.dat = dataObj;
t.medianTime = t.dat.medianTime || t.MEDIAN_TIME,
```

Whats the difference between adding semicolon or comma for the statements.
Please someone suggests for the proper documents for JSLint.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, a semicolon will end a statement, while a comma is used to gather several variable declarations into one single statement (among other uses). For example:

```
var myNumericVar = 1,
    myBooleanVar = false;
```

This would be the equivalent to

```
var myNumericVar = 1;
var myBooleanVar = false;
```

Back to your question, JSLint should stop complaining if you replace the comma by a semicolon.